# Backdrop-filter doesn't work on Safari (most of the times)

Tags: css, safari

I'm using Safari for the very first time and I noticed something weird about the backdrop filters, while they work on some sections, they just refuse to do so on other ones. Or, they load randomly one time (I noticed that this usually happens after clearing the cache but since I'm working on an expandable menu, the next time I close it and reopen it again, the filter is gone) and... yeah, I've pretty much just cleared it up... they are gone once again. What's the reason for that?

```
nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 0px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    z-index: 8;
    margin-top: 50px;
    transition: all 700ms;
}
```

Comment: What version of Safari? Also Safari requires an `x-` prefix = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Unfortunately, the `x-` prefix did not work.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: That's supposed to be long? Shouldn't I provide more for such problems, the issue may occur because of other properties...

Comment: The point is to *demonstrate* the problem. By removing / adding as much code as is required to show us the issue you might actually find what is causing it.

Comment: See [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter - Safari needs -webkit- prefix on backdrop-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a redraw/repaint bug. I've had similar, where the backdrop filter doesn't display until you trigger a redraw by editing something in the devtools for example.

For my use case, I waited until transitionend before triggering a repaint

```
setTimeout(() => {
  el.style.display = "table";
  el.offsetHeight;
  el.style.display = "block";
});
```

There are other methods of course for triggering it, but that should point you in the right direction.